# FOR /F processing of CSV with differing number of variables

Tags: for-loop, cmd, batch-processing

I'm trying to write a batch script to move thousands of folders from their current location to a new location. I have a CSV with the original/new location info, as such:

[full path of current location],new_dir_1,new_subdir_2,[new_subdir_3],[etc],

In the past I've had good luck using FOR /F, and that's what I'm trying here.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %g in (text_file.csv) do xcopy "%%g" "d:\%%h\%%i\%%j" /e /i /y
```

Fails where there aren't enough tokens for variables and I get two trailing backslashes in my destination path.

```
for /f "tokens=* ....
```

Fails as well - my understanding was that "tokens=*" would create a token per comma-separated term but maybe I have that wrong? It appears, rather, to take the entire line as one token.

Is there a way to modify my "do" command to only create the destination path as deep as necessary (i.e., if new_subdir_3 doesn't exist, the path should be "d:\new_dir1\new_subdir_2\" and not "d:\new_dir1\new_subdir_2\")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tokens=*` or `tokens=1,*` does not work as you think. It will set an aditional replaceable parameter that will contain the rest of the line after the last required token. That is, all the line in the first case or from the second to the end in the second case. But only one variable/replaceable parameter is defined for the `*`

There is an easy way to solve your problem . Just use an aditional `for` loop to handle the problematic path

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%g in (text_file.csv) do (
    for %%a in ("d:\%%~h\%%~i\%%~j\.") do  xcopy "%%~g" "%%~fa" /e /i /y
)
```

The `%%~fa` will return the full path generated by `d:\%%~h\%%~i\%%~j\.`, but all the double backslashes will be removed in the process.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! Do you have a link to documentation on the %%~fa, etc.?

Comment: @Josh, `for /?` will give you all the needed information.